# NavigationDrawer disable right swipe

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have DrawerLayout setup with a drawer on either side

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />


<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_right"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />
```

The right drawer is populated when a certain method is run, however, before that method is run I can swipe from the right and the screen dims but nothing shows (because the layout is empty until the method has been run).

How can I disable swipe from the right until the method has been run? I've seen solutions to fully disable any swiping, but that wouldn't work for me as the left drawer needs to always work (the setup right draw function is called when a particular option is selected on the left drawer).

Or, would there be a better way to do this? Maybe dynamically adding the right FrameLayout when the function is run?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This disables the swipe:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_right);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

And to enable swipe:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit updated answer.
You need to pass right drawer view to disable swipe on it.

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, findViewById(R.id.right_drawer));
```

Comment: also you can do `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);`

Answer (score 4):

Just to mention an interesting observation.

In case you are using a layout structure for having left AND right side menus like this one:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->

    <include layout="@layout/content_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>


<!-- LEFT SIDE MENU -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_side_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@color/green">


    <!-- put some menu items in here -->

</RelativeLayout>



<!-- RIGHT SIDE MENU -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_side_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@color/gray">

    <!-- put some items in here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

You're gonna have some hard time trying to disable only one of the side menus
with statements like this one:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, findViewById(R.id.right_drawer))
```

That will lock the whole DrawerLayout and you won't be able to swipe neither of the side menus.

Thus, the method proposed by @Alberto Maluje, under one of the answers above, will give you more flexibility.

> mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);